Capybara does not visit routes inside rails 7.2 application
I have always used Capybara with Rspec and with Rails 4, 5, and 6 - inside Docker containers without Selenium - to run end-to-end tests.
Now, with Rails 7.2, the same tests fail because Capybara, instead of accessing the application's resources, loads www.example.com with 'visit'.
I haven't been able to find any valid references online; has anyone encountered the same issue and can help me?
The dev env is:

OSX on Mac M1 ver. 14.5
Docker version 27.1.1, build 6312585
ruby 3.3.4 (2024-07-09 revision be1089c8ec) [aarch64-linux]
Rails 7.2.0
rspec-core 3.13.0
rspec-expectations 3.13.1
rspec-mocks 3.13.1
rspec-rails 6.1.4
rspec-support 3.13.1
Capybara 3.40.0

Here an example from scratch,:
#
# spec/features/post_spec.rb
#
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'Posts', type: :feature do
  it 'visitings' do
    visit '/posts'
    expect(page).to have_content 'New post'
  end
end

# docker exec -it app-container-name rspec 
F.
Failures:

  1) Posts visitings
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content 'New post'
       expected to find text "New post" in "Blocked hosts: www.example.com\nTo allow requests to these hosts, make sure they are valid hostnames (containing only numbers, letters, dashes and dots), then add the following to your environment configuration:\nconfig.hosts << \"www.example.com\"\nFor more details view: the Host Authorization guide"
     # ./spec/features/post_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.09256 seconds (files took 2.87 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/post_spec.rb:4 # Posts visitings

This is an excerpt from a simple test application, but even porting a complete application from Rails 4 shows the same issue!
Tanks

After further investigation with other examples, I have found the solution: the issue lies in the development environment setup within the Dockerfile:
ENV RAILS_ENV="development" BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development”.
Once this configuration was removed, Capybara correctly accessed the application's resources.
